# JQuery .attr is not a function for sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I need to change the src of image using JQuery.

`<a class="cbs-ItemLink" title="2E2" id="ctl00_ctl39_g_590482e6_7a32_435e_bcd5_0662381d98a8_csr1_2lines_pictureLink">` `<img class="cbs-Thumbnail" src="/Style%20Library/16x16.ico" alt="2E2" id="ctl00_ctl39_g_590482e6_7a32_435e_bcd5_0662381d98a8_csr1_2lines_picture"> </a>`

```
$("a.cbs-ItemLink img").attr('src','some value')
```

I have tried many things  but it is giving the same error that attr is not a function.

**Updated Question:-**

Can you help me how to do it for all **li tags** like

```
  <li><div class="cbs-Item" data-displaytemplate="Item2Lines"><a class="cbs-ItemLink" title="2E2"><img class="cbs-Thumbnail" src="/Style%20Library/sharepoint-icon-32038-16x16.ico" alt="2E2">            </a><div class="cbs-Detail"><a class="cbs-Line1Link ms-noWrap ms-displayBlock" href="DMS/2E2" title="2E2">2E2</a></div></div</li>`
```

Answer (score 1):

If attr is not a function then `$("a.cbs-ItemLink img")` is not returning a DOM element

Check in F12 Console what `$("a.cbs-ItemLink img")` returns

Possible causes why it is not working inside the page:

- DOM element doesn't exist yet when the code executes

#### Vanilla JavaScript (no jQuery required)

(*More typing, saves you the hassle of loading a 90 KB library*)

**check value in the F12 console**

`document.querySelector("a.cbs-ItemLink img")`

Should return DOM element

**assign value**

`document.querySelector("a.cbs-ItemLink img").src = 'some value';`

Comment: Yes this works for one item but can you please help me with the updated question, I need it to work for all li tags

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=loop+dom+elements

Comment: I have used `$("#ctl00_ctl39_g_590482e6_7a32_435e__csr > ul > li").each(function(){
 document.querySelector("a.cbs-ItemLink img").src = '/Style%20Library/sharepoint-icon-32038-16x16.ico';
})` But this is only changing first item..

Comment: and also it is changing for first item when I do it from console in browser, but its not working when I have kept the code in .ready function. I have debugged also but not able to find exact reason. Please help me...

Comment: Don't try and fix all problems in one try. Your first problem is that the DOM element is not available in the Browser in your document.ready function; **fix the first problem First**. Only you can fix this because only you have access to the environment. If you don't have enough JavaScript/DOM skills then you have to fix that problem first. Read blogs, see YouTube videos. It is like making a cake, if you can not make dough there is no point in trying to work with the sugar frosting.

Comment: Thanks danny, I have done it by making changes in the display template directly.

Comment: Those are terrible to debug... make small changes to learn what code does... break things, learn by fixing them. If you make too many changes at once you are not learning. Go back to the last template that works, then try and figure out why the DOM element returned is empty...it could  be an async loading issue where Microsoft loads content **after** the ready event.. learn to use the standard ``window.setTimeout`` (but only to figure out what is going on)

Comment: To see what Templates do you could also set the Network throttling in F12 tools to simulate a 3G (or 2G) connection... that will give you seconds to minutes to see what is displayed/loaded when